# RayCast seems to sometimes hit mesh in Blender 2.69

Tags: python, scene

I would like to check if my camera has line-of-sight of an Empty, and I need to use Blender 2.69 although I only have 2.78 on my own system. I'm using `ray_cast` to determine line of sight, and it appears to work in 2.78 but not 2.69! Here's my process.

For Blender 2.78 I open up my .ply file and import the mesh, and then load in both where I'll put my camera (`camera_location`) and where I'll put the empty (`empty_location`). I don't actually create any objects just yet. Then, I use the following code to detect line-of-sight.

```
direction = empty_location - Vector(camera_location)
(ray_hit, location, normal, index, obj, matrix) = scene.ray_cast( camera_location, direction )
```

And it will hit the mesh and return the expected values.

Now in Blender 2.69, I use a the same process, but invoke `ray_cast` differently because it is parametrized differently:

```
(ray_hit, obj, matrix, location, normal) = scene.ray_cast( camera_location, empty_location )
```

And *sometimes* it returns the expected values. Other times it seems to miss the mesh altogether and just returns `ray_hit=False, location=<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>`

Does anyone know why this could be and ideally, a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that the cast ray stops at `end`. In some cases, precision errors might cause the ray to stop before actually hitting the mesh. In my case, making the ray go twice as far solved the problem. Use

```
direction = empty_location - Vector(camera_location)
(ray_hit, obj, matrix, location, normal) = scene.ray_cast( camera_location, empty_location + direction )
```

for Blender 2.69